# Installation (windows installer - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: system-installation

Installation (windows installer - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

I downloaded the (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) ISO file then the (Install Ubuntu with the Windows installer) it fully installed and restarted.

Then I chose the Ubuntu OS and black screen... so I ESC and started in SAFE MODE and got "_" symbol flashing (to type something in) but turns off few seconds and black screen... have to force shutdown.

Please help thanks.
Michael

Comment: I'm using a eMachines EZ1711 Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit

Comment: no joy, done the boot - purple screen - icons on bottom with man hands up - pressed enter - english - f6 - nomodest - enter - x - press esc, enter "try ubuntu without installing"   got purple screen Ubuntu 12.04 [ 34.403024] kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000600 [ 34.403024]  BLACK SCREEN - Had to unplug the usb pen drive - and had to do a system restore to get back windows.

Comment: trying the Ubuntu 12.07 LTS (32bit version i386) on external usb stick (32gb) ntfs formatted. Ubuntu Installer done.

Comment: finally got it to work :D     I right mouse clicked on the ubuntu (windows installer) app and put it onto the usb stick (32gb) ntfs stick and try ubuntu without installing.